# Get items from Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

How can I get the date from this Hashmap.
How can I get the variable purpose?
I want this data and convert it then into a dateformat.

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
    String[] from = { "name", "purpose" };
    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData() {
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    list.add(putData("A", "20.7.2013"));
    list.add(putData("B", "21.7.2013"));
    list.add(putData("C", "22.7.2013"));
    return list;
}

public HashMap<String, String> putData(String name, String purpose) {
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("name", name);
    item.put("purpose", purpose);
    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DateFormat to convert from String to Date.
May be something like this can help you

```
private void getDate(){
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    for( Map<String, String> m : list){
        String dateStr = m.get("A");
        Date formated = format.parse(dateStr);// This will parse the String i.e. purpose and return the date obj

    }
}
```

EDITED
Use

```
public HashMap<String, String> putData(String name, String purpose) {
HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
item.put(name, purpose);
return item;
```

}

Comment: how can I do this with variable if someone clicks on a item of this list? And why cant find it the variable list?

Comment: @KW : the way you are storing into map is incorrect i feel.    Store in the map as  
    item.put(name, purpose); and then you can retieve the purpose field using the code given earlier.